# Lambda - {"message": "Internal server error"}

Tags: aws-lambda

Riddle me this!

Why lambda?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"first_name":"ABCDE", "last_name": "john"}' https://8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/HelloPython

{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

It works in the lambda test!  Granted I am new but still How do I find out why?  All I need in cloud metrics is a count of 500 errors.  But I want to know why.  I am doing a simple hello world.

```
import json
def respond(err, res=None):
    return {
        'statusCode': '400' if err else '200',
        'body': err.message if err else json.dumps(res),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }

def my_handler(event, context):


    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'], 
                                    event['last_name'])  
    res = {'message' : message }
    return respond(None, res)
```

update - Below is the logs:

```
'first_name': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/hello_python.py", line 68, in my_handler
message = 'Hello
{}
{}
!'.format(event['first_name'],
KeyError: 'first_name'
```

I am confused.  Is the events a what type of object?  If a string do I need do use json.loads(event) to get a dict object?

Comment: can you please share the cloudwatch logs as well?

Comment: In the monitoring tab, click &quot;View in CloudWatch Logs&quot; this will give you the Logs for each run

Comment: i added the logs

Comment: So `first_name` is not being passed into the Lambda function. You should try logging the entire `event` object so you can see what is going on. Perhaps there is an issue with your API Gateway mapping template.

Answer (score 2):

I typically dont like answering my own question but as a newbie to lambda I hope this helps someone.

1) the event data looks like this:

```
{
    u 'body': u '{"first_name":"ABCDE", "last_name": "john"}', u 'resource': u '/HelloPython', u 'requestContext': {
        u 'resourceId': u 'kl9',
        u 'apiId': u '81s0q',
        u 'resourcePath': u '/HelloPython',
        u 'httpMethod': u 'POST',
        u 'requestId': u 'e1c72ee6-7-9059-1bd746727831',
        u 'path': u '/prod/HelloPython',
        u 'accountId': u 'cccc',
        u 'identity': {
            u 'apiKey': u '',
            u 'userArn': None,
            u 'cognitoAuthenticationType': None,
            u 'accessKey': None,
            u 'caller': None,
            u 'userAgent': u 'curl/7.54.0',
            u 'user': None,
            u 'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None,
            u 'cognitoIdentityId': None,
            u 'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None,
            u 'sourceIp': u 'ccccc',
            u 'accountId': None
        },
        u 'stage': u 'prod'
    }, u 'queryStringParameters': None, u 'httpMethod': u 'POST', u 'pathParameters': None, u 'headers': {
        u 'Content-Type': u 'application/json',
        u 'Via': u '1.1 07c960c5d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
        u 'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': u 'true',
        u 'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': u 'false',
        u 'CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto': u 'https',
        u 'X-Forwarded-For': u 'xxx, cccc',
        u 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': u 'US',
        u 'Accept': u '*/*',
        u 'User-Agent': u 'curl/7.54.0',
        u 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': u 'Root=1-59f4e74a9fecde',
        u 'Host': u '81s0q.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
        u 'X-Forwarded-Proto': u 'https',
        u 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': u 'GXnihIB370EYguOCiGYEA==',
        u 'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': u 'false',
        u 'X-Forwarded-Port': u '443',
        u 'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': u 'false'
    }, u 'stageVariables': None, u 'path': u '/HelloPython', u 'isBase64Encoded': False
}
```

2) data is in body that then has to be loaded from json:

```
test = json.loads(event['body'])  
message = "Dude %s %s" % (test['first_name'],  test['last_name'])
```

Curl now works